# ScrollMagic with React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get ScrollMagic working with ES2015 import and React. I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'TimelineMax' in /Users/dillonraphael/Desktop/marbleshark_landingpage/node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins
 @ ./~/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js 31:2-61
```

This is how I'm importing everything.

```
import {gsap, TimelineMax, TweenMax} from 'gsap';
import ScrollMagic from 'ScrollMagic';
require('scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap');
```

Comment: why are you importing and requiring the same thing? unless you need to do that maybe put the require above the imports?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Without requiring animation.gsap I get a different error. ERROR calling setTween() due to missing Plugin 'animation.gsap'. Please make sure to include plugins/animation.gsap.js

Comment: what I was asking is I see you import some things from gsap and you also import ScrollMagic... then you require scrollmagic animations.gsap. what is the difference between them? why are you using a require instead of an import? all that aside did you try putting the require above the imports?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I was experimenting with some answers I found around online. And ya I did, and get the error: ERROR calling setTween() due to missing Plugin 'animation.gsap'. Please make sure to include plugins/animation.gsap.js

Comment: @Dileet did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

Using this `import` statement works for me:

```
import * as ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'
```

after installing the package with `npm install scrollmagic`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do:

Webpack:

```js
config.resolve.alias = {
      ScrollMagic: path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js'),
};
```

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const ScrollMagic = require('ScrollMagic');
    const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({ globalSceneOptions: { triggerHook: 0 } });
}
```